# Block a navigation controller from navigating and ask for user confirmation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` that uses `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to init a view controller with `initWithNibName:`. The user is able to return to the table view but I would like to perform a if/else and display an alert view to confirm if the user would like to return to the table view. I have no clues where to start.

In short, I would like to customize the back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you create a `UIBarButtonItem` instance and assign it to the view controller's navigation item? Something like this,

```
UIBarButtonItem * backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                target:self
                                                                action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

and then in `backButtonPressed:`, trigger an alert view.

```
- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // Trigger an alert view.
}
```

Based on the user choice, you can pop the view controller or not.

Comment: great! thats what I needed. I managed to custom the button and the trigger works! but what do I add into the code for it to function like the normal back button? because now it doesn't go back anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The button that returns the user is an IBAction (or it's a method that you define when you set the button up programmatically), so you can add the code from [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2982-2-button-uialertview-button-pressed.html#post15596) into the IBAction and put the code to return in

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Comment: that seems like it would work to block the navigation controller from navigating but I would like it the other way round. The tableviewcontroller uses the navigationcontroller to init the view controller. I would like to catch it when it's returning to the tableview. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to catch it when it's returning?  You would want to catch it when the user hits the button, like in your original question and title.

Comment: the nav controller inits a view controller, in which the user may make changes. i would like to check if the user would like to save/discard the changes before the "back" code executes.

Comment: You've just flip flopped again.  Maybe I didn't make my answer clear enough.  There's a method that gets called when the user hits the back button, which goes to the previous view, instead, make it call an alert view, and use that method I posted above to check for the "OK" press to go to the prev. view.